# How the model class works in C#

Tags: c#, .net

```
  public class Program {

    public static void Main(string[] args) {
      
      Person person = new Person();
      person.name = "from main function";
      
      Program pro = new Program();

      Console.WriteLine(person.name);

      pro.change(person);

      Console.WriteLine(person.name);
    }

    public void change(Person per) {
      per.name = "From public void Change function";
    }

    public class Person {
      public string name {get; set;}
    }

  }
}
```

why is the person object overwritten by the change function?
because I have different objects for the person's class

Comment: this is C#, not C/C++. Since `Person` is declared as `class`, you'll always deal with a reference of the instance.

Comment: The object stays the same (instance). Only its `name` property will be mutated. What about this is surprising to you and why?

Comment: "I have different objects" - no, you create exactly one Person object (in the line `Person person = new Person();`), and pass this object to the `change` method.

Comment: Maybe creating new `Program` confuses things a little, but it has nothing to do with anything, you don't need even need new Program object, mark change method as static and use it from Main directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C#, when you pass an object to a method, you are not making a copy of the object. Instead, you are telling the method where to find the original object in the computer's memory. This is like giving the method a map with the object's location.

Now, because both the original object and the object inside the method are pointing to the same memory location (like two different arrows pointing to the same spot), any changes made to the object inside the method will also affect the original object. It's like if you make changes to something on the map, it will affect the real thing in that location.

So, be careful when you pass objects to methods. If you modify the object inside the method, those changes will show up in the original object because both are pointing to the same place in the computer's memory. If you want to keep the original object unchanged, you need to create a new copy of the object inside the method and work with that copy instead.

Answer (score 1):

Here you pass a reference type `Person` by value. In this case, the `change()` method **receives a copy of the reference to the class instance**. Since the `change()` method has the address of the instance, it can change the members of the `per` object.

**EDIT:** To make things clear, let's elaborate the topic by *comparing the differences of passing a class instance (reference type) and a struct instance (value type) to a method*.

### Passing a Class Instance to a Method:

When you pass the `person` object to the `change()` method then the reference (or memory address) of the `person` object is given to the `per` object in the method parameter as shown in the following figure:

[image]

So both `person` and `per` objects point to the same memory address, i.e. **both refer to the same object**. Therefore it is not a surprise that when the `per` object changes its `name` property then the `person` object will see that change.

### Passing a Struct Instance to a Method:

Let's assume `Person` is a `struct` and then look at what will change.
Since a `struct` is a value type, when you pass the `person` object to the `change()` method, the method receives and operates on a copy of the struct argument (`per` in our case). The `change()` method has no access to the original struct (`person`) in the calling method and therefore can't change it in any way. The method can change only the copy. **There are two independent copies of the `Person` struct** as in the following figure shows:

[image]

Two independent copies means when you change the `name` property in the `change()` method, the `name` property of the `person` object *will not change*. To see this, change the type of the `Person` to struct:

```
public struct Person
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

When you run the program the output will be

```
"from main function"
"from main function"
```

which is different than the result you got in the question.

Comment: While technically correct, this is confusing. I think you need to reword.

Comment: This topic (passing by value/by reference etc.) has already an inherent confusion ;)

Comment: So explain it clearly instead. Vivek did this well.